# How to get value item in asyncstorage?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

In my log value is **{"namecity":"India"}** but I want only India in my value, how to get it

```js
AsyncStorage.getItem('cityname').then((cityname) => {
    if (cityname) {
        this.setState({ city: cityname });
        console.log(this.state.city);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your object is JSON encoded. Use JSON parse and you access the key value.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('cityname').then((cityname) => {
        if(cityname){
            const decodedCity = JSON.parse(cityname);
            this.setState({city: decodedCity['namecity']});
            console.log(this.state.city);
        }
});
```